# sudo needed to create a build through terminal

Tags: command-line, sudo, nodejs, npm

I'm using [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) with [NPM/NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and instead of creating a build through `vuepress build` it needs **sudo** to make it work.  `sudo vuepress build`

How to make it work without sudo?

Error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/@vuepress/core/.temp/app-enhancers'
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the command and all the error messages. Further, do `ls -ld .` and check the permissions/ownership of the current directory.

Comment: Thank you, added the error message. You're right, it's an issue with the permissions. Do I need to change them for the /node_modules or root /usr?

Comment: Edit your question, and show us the results of `ls -ld .` and `id`. Maybe your solution needs `adduser`, maybe not.

Comment: Probably you have [to change the path where your npm installed packages go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712034/4970442), somewhere with $USER rights.